# Using a SQL cursor. Worried about performance. Any way to do this with set operations?

Tags: sql, t-sql, cursor

I am working on a production table that constantly updates, it is in its infancy, but eventually there may be multiple insertions per minute to this table (and will likely reach millions of entries). I have **no control** over the table structure or how data is input.

I need to count the number of _COFF's made **after** a machine has the status of _SETUP. This count must be made at **least** every 15 minutes. The ID is used as a key in another table, and must be associated with the MachineNumber and PartNumber in the output. (sample output below)

Here is what i am working with:

'Production' table:

```
+---------------+---------------------+---------+------------+--------+
| MachineNumber |      DateTime       | Comment | PartNumber | Status |
+---------------+---------------------+---------+------------+--------+
|             1 | 11/11/2014 12:12:32 |         |        104 | _SETUP |
|             1 | 11/11/2014 12:12:40 |     155 |        104 | _ID    |
|             1 | 11/11/2014 12:12:45 |         |        104 | _CON   |
|             1 | 11/11/2014 12:16:45 |         |        104 | _COFF  |
|             1 | 11/11/2014 12:16:46 |         |        104 | _CON   |
|             1 | 11/11/2014 12:20:46 |         |        104 | _COFF  |
|             2 | 11/11/2014 12:20:50 |         |        223 | _SETUP |
|             1 | 11/11/2014 12:21:00 |         |        104 | _CON   |
|             1 | 11/11/2014 12:23:00 |         |        104 | _COFF  |
|             2 | 11/11/2014 12:25:00 |     543 |        223 | _ID    |
|             2 | 11/11/2014 12:25:20 |         |        223 | _CON   |
|             2 | 11/11/2014 12:26:20 |         |        223 | _COFF  |
            ...             ...             ...         ...      ...                       
+---------------+---------------------+---------+------------+--------+
```

Currently i use a cursor to get the following output:

```
+---------------+------------+-----+-------------+
| MachineNumber |  DateTime  | ID  | _COFF Count |
+---------------+------------+-----+-------------+
|             1 | 11/11/2014 | 155 |           3 |
|             2 | 11/11/2014 | 543 |           1 |
+---------------+------------+-----+-------------+
```

Anyway to do this better than looping through (possibly) a million entries? What about deleting records from the table i have already looped through, and storing the output in another table?

EDIT: There will be only one _SETUP and one _ID per part per machine, there will more than one part per machine however (and therefore more than one _SETUP and _ID for each machine in the table).

Comment: One flag, please. Your dbms is either MySQL or TSQL (ms-sql), pick one. Also, you include date/time here with the time stripped out in your desired output, does this mean you want the counts for a given Machine/Part/ID broken down into counts/day?

Comment: could you tell us the table ID. also, is there only one _SETUP per machine number?

Comment: What if there is more than one _setup?  What if there is more than one _ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best thing would be creating a trigger which would reset the last setup date for a machine, then use it in an indexed view.

Assuming your table is called `Status`:

```
CREATE INDEX
        IX_Status_Machine_Status_DateTime
ON      Status (machineNumber, status, dateTime)
GO

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX
        UX_Status_Machine_Part__Id
ON      Status (machineNumber, partNumber)
WHERE   status = '_ID'

CREATE TABLE
        Status_LastSetup
        (
        machineNumber INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
        partNumber INT NOT NULL,
        lastSetup DATETIME NOT NULL
        )
GO

CREATE TRIGGER
        TR_Status_All
ON      Status
AFTER   INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS
WITH    c AS
        (
        SELECT  machineNumber
        FROM    INSERTED
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  machineNumber
        FROM    DELETED
        ),
        t AS
        (
        SELECT  sls.*
        FROM    c
        JOIN    Status_LastSetup sls
        ON      sls.machineNumber = c.machineNumber
        ),
        s AS
        (
        SELECT  *
        FROM    c
        CROSS APPLY
                (
                SELECT  TOP 1
                        partNumber, dateTime
                FROM    Status st
                WHERE   st.machineNumber = c.machineNumber
                        AND st.status = '_STATE'
                ORDER BY
                        dateTime DESC
                )
        )
ON      t.machineNumber = s.machineNumber
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
INSERT  (machineNumber, partNumber, lastSetup)
VALUES  (s.machineNumber, s.partNumber, s.dateTime)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE
SET     t.dateTime = s.dateTime,
        t.partNumber = s.partNumber
WHERE   EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  t.dateTime, t.partNumber
        EXCEPT
        SELECT  s.dateTime, s.partNumber
        )
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN
DELETE
GO

CREATE VIEW
        V_Status_CoffCount
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT  s.machineNumber,
        COUNT_BIG(*) cnt
FROM    dbo.Status_LastSetup sls
JOIN    dbo.Status s
ON      s.machineNumber = sls.machineNumber
        AND s.status = '_COFF'
        AND s.dateTime >= sls.lastSetup
GROUP BY
        s.machineNumber
GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX
        UX_V_Status_CoffCount_Machine
ON      V_Status_CoffCount (machineNumber)
GO
```

Once it's all up and running, just run this query:

```
SELECT  s.machineNumber, sls.lastSetup, comment id, cnt
FROM    V_Status_CoffCount scc WITH (NOEXPAND)
JOIN    Status_LastSetup sls
ON      sls.machineNumber = scc.machineNumber
LEFT JOIN
        Status s
ON      s.machineNumber = sls.machineNumber
        AND s.partNumber = sls.partNumber
        AND s.status = '_ID'
```

Its execution time is linear to the number of machines you have and (almost) does not depend on the number of entries in `Status`.

See this all on SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9671c/2

Answer (score 0):

```
select table.machinenumber, timestamp.starttime, id.comment, count(*) 
  from table 
  join ( select MachineNumber, min(comment) as commment
           from table
          where Status = '_ID' 
            and comment is not null 
          group by MachineNumber ) as id 
    on id.MachineNumber = table.machinenumber 
  join ( select MachineNumber, min(datetime) as starttime
           from table 
          where Status = '_SETUP'
          group by MachineNumber ) as timestamp 
     on timestamp.ID = table.ID 
    and timestamp.starttime < table.datetime 
    and table.Status = '_CON'
  group by table.machinenumber, timestamp.starttime, id.comment
```